# Navigation bar background image responsivity, with another container on the right

Tags: html, css, background, navigation, responsive

Im trying to make my navigation bar responsive, but it has a background and I can't simply add it a 100% width,because next to it, on the right, there is a notification-panel, with a fix width, and if I add 100% width to the navbar, it spreads to the container width, and forces the notification-panel under it.
So what I need is to have the notification-panel with fix width on the right of the page, and if decreasing the width of the screen, the notification-panel must be decreasing the navbar's width (navbar would be responsive). Im attaching my codes real simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="proba.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="notification-panel">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
 .container{
    max-width:1200px;
    height:1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding:0px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.navbar{
    width:100%;  /*there should be the 100% to make the navbar responsive*/
    height: 58px;
    background-image: url('menu.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.notification-panel {
    float:left;
    width:230px;
    height:800px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Thank you guys

Comment: You can use `width: calc(100% - 230px);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `calc()`

```css
 .container {
   max-width: 1200px;
   height: 1000px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding: 0px;
   border: 1px solid red;
 }
 
 .navbar {
   width: calc(100% - 235px);
   height: 58px;
   background-image: url('menu.png');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   float: left;
   margin-left: 5px;
 }
 
 .notification-panel {
   float: left;
   width: 230px;
   height: 800px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="notification-panel">
</div>
</div>
```

or flexbox with `flex-grow: 1;` on `.navbar` so it will grow to take up all the available space left over from the notification panel

```css
 .container {
   max-width: 1200px;
   height: 1000px;
   margin: 0px auto;
   padding: 0px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   display: flex;
 }
 
 .navbar {
   flex-grow: 1;
   /*there should be the 100% to make the navbar responsive*/
   height: 58px;
   background-image: url('menu.png');
   background-size: 100% 100%;
 }
 
 .notification-panel {
   width: 230px;
   height: 800px;
   border: 1px solid red;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="notification-panel">
  </div>
</div>
```